# binary tree explanation why does this work

Tags: python, binary-search

Started reading a book about basic data structures and algorithms which uses this example code,

```
    def binary_search(list, item):
    low = 0  
    high = len(list)-1  #sets upper range to length of provided list

    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) #why does (low + high) give me middle of list?
        guess = list[mid]
        if guess == item:
            return mid
        if guess > item:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1
    return None

my_list = [1,3,5,7,9]

print binary_search(my_list,3)
print binary_search(my_list,-1)
```

While I understand the concept of the tree I don't understand why

`mid = (low + high) #why does (low + high) give me middle of list`?
wouldn't low + high just give me the same value as high? shouldn't i need low + high / 2 to find the midpoint? yet it works perfectly fine?

Comment: isnt meant to be (low+high) //2 ?

Comment: You are rigth it should be `mid = (low + high)//2`. It still works because it does not require the middle but it runs longer as is only goes through the complete list instead of "skipping" over is

Comment: "//" 2 solved my other problem of getting back crazy decimals in python shell as well thanks! at this point i needed to go back and look at the operators I never really used before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because `mid` is always in the right range, but this is linear search, not binary. You can check this by printing the indices that are examined:

```
def binary_search(list, item):
    low = 0  
    high = len(list)-1  #sets upper range to length of provided list

    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) #why does (low + high) give me middle of list?
        print("mid =", mid)
        guess = list[mid]
        if guess == item:
            return mid
        if guess > item:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1
```

Looking for -1 in your example:

```
>>> print (binary_search([1,3,5,7,9],-1))
mid = 4
mid = 3
mid = 2
mid = 1
mid = 0
None
```

So you are correct: you should divide `mid` by 2 (and avoid using `list` as a variable name).

Answer (score 1):

It should indeed be `(low+high)//2`.  As it is now, `mid` starts from the last item in the list and always goes through the else part of the `guess>item` condition.  So `high` is reduced by 1 each time and `low` never changes (from zero). The process ends up going through all elements from last to first which is not a binary search at all (rather a sequential search).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about this being incorrect!

It will give you the correct result, but let's look at what's actually happening.

```
  if guess == item:
    return mid
  if guess > item:
    high = mid - 1
  else:
    low = mid + 1
```

In the first iteration, `guess == list[mid] == list[high] == 9`. 3 is less than 9, so high will decrement.

In the next iteration, again `mid == high`, but high is 1 less.

high will continue to decrement until `guess == list[mid] == list[high] == list[1] == 3`